# Stretching a Leaflet Map to any size

Tags: vuejs2, leaflet

My Leaflet Map (Custom one) is relatively small, i made tiles from a 16000x16000 image and implemented them into the website with Leaflet, but the map is too small, the `minZoom: 2` is too big and the `minZoom 1` is too small.

[image: Here the Image]

I would like the Map to fill the whole gray area (which is my map area) but the tiles right now dont fill the whole thing, with bounds i can keep it centered but still not bigger. Any help appreciated.

EDIT 1:

```
 <l-map ref="map" :zoomSnap="zoomSnap" :minZoom="minZoom" :maxZoom="maxZoom" :options="mapOptions" style="background-color: lightgray; width: fill; height: 100%;" :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
          <l-tile-layer :options="mapOptions" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" :url="url" :attribution="attribution"></l-tile-layer>
</l-map>
```

Comment: Adding some css to the map div, height: 100%; and width: 100%; or maybe I'm not understanding what your trying to do

Comment: @Tony the gray area is the same div as the white box

Comment: could you add your code to https://jsfiddle.net so I can understanding more

Comment: @Tony editet it, i cant reproduce it on jsfiddle i cant upload my assets there, but my edit basicly shows the code of the screenshot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the map [`zoomSnap`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-zoomsnap) option:

> Forces the map's zoom level to always be a multiple of this, particularly right after a `fitBounds()` or a pinch-zoom. By default, the zoom level snaps to the nearest integer; lower values (e.g. `0.5` or `0.1`) allow for greater granularity. A value of `0` means the zoom level will not be snapped after fitBounds or a pinch-zoom.

I suspect you use Vue and Vue2Leaflet plugin.

Your `zoomSnap` data should most probably be a member of your `mapOptions` data that you pass to the `options` prop of the `<l-map>` component, instead of being its own prop / attribute.

You would probably also be interested in using the map [`zoomDelta`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-zoomdelta) option:

> Controls how much the map's zoom level will change after a `zoomIn()`, `zoomOut()`, pressing `+` or `-` on the keyboard, or using the zoom controls. Values smaller than `1` (e.g. `0.5`) allow for greater granularity.

Comment: Thanks, i also got that idea and tried it before but the Thing was i gave the ZoomSnap as a new Property instead of putting it into the Options of my map. 

After reading yours i tried to implement it into the Options instead and it worked perfectly, thanks a lot!